# About local planner?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'd like to implement a new local planner in move_base.
My new planner is based on a Fuzzy-PID controller and is implemented in c++.

My question is: can I integrate it in the ROS's navigation stack? and how match is it difficult or easy to do?

waiting for your answers and your help.
Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191750/about-local-planner-?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To integrate a **custom local planner** with the navigation stack is **fairly easy:** You need to **write a plugin** for [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) that adheres to the [nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_core/html/classnav__core_1_1BaseLocalPlanner.html) interface.

You can find documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/nav_core#BaseLocalPlanner) and as an example you can take a look at the code of the [dwa_local_planner](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/hydro-devel/dwa_local_planner) (pay special attention to [dwa_planner_ros.h](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/dwa_local_planner/include/dwa_local_planner/dwa_planner_ros.h) and [dwa_planner_ros.cpp](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/dwa_local_planner/src/dwa_planner_ros.cpp))

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3